# XML Post request through chrome console (FB)

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I am trying to make simple post request to local host, through the console while Im on facebook. I am unable to make the request and keep getting this error:

```
VM637:4 Refused to connect to 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* *.akamaihd.net wss://*.facebook.com:* https://fb.scanandcleanlocal.com:* *.atlassolutions.com attachment.fbsbx.com ws://localhost:* blob: *.cdninstagram.com chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm".
(anonymous function) @ VM637:4
VM637:4 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to connect to 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.(…)
```

I am trying to send page elements which makes this the best way to do it and accessing the DOM with chrome extensions is too difficult. Please let me know how I can override the **content security policy** to make API calls in the console.

Comment: Well same origin policy is there to protect you. If this is for you, you can start your browser up with flags to ignore the security settings.

Comment: @epascarello, do you see what I'm trying to do? is there anyway I can do all of it through the console in a normal browser?

Comment: `in a normal browser?` - what is a normal browser? Is there any way you can violate Content Security Policy? No, unless ...